# 4 professors and 7 students are to be seated on 11 chairs. What is the probability that every professor is between 2 students?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> There are 4 professors and 7 students to be sited on 11 chairs. What is a probability that every professor is between 2 students?

---

**My thoughts:** There is $11!$ outcomes. Good ones are: first we arrange the professors on $4!$ ways, then we put 7 chairs so that on left and right side is at least one chair and between every two professor is one chair. That we can do on ${6\choose 2}$ ways by solving the equation $$a+b+c+d+e = 7$$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are natural numbers.

Now we arrange the students on empty chairs, and that we can do on $7!$ ways. So the probability is $$P = {4!\cdot 15\cdot 7!\over 11!}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: How did you get that the number of natural solutions of the equation $a+b+c+d+e=7$ is $15$? I agree with that number, but I fail to see how is it that you got it as $\binom62$.

Comment: It is the same as $(a-1)+(b-1)+... = 2$, so it is the same as to solve $a'+b'+...=2$ in nonegative integers.

Comment: Yes, but, again, I don't see where the $\binom62$ comes from. I would say that there are $5$ solutions in which one of the numbers is $2$ and all others are $0$ and $\binom52$ solutions in which two of the numbers are $1$ and all others are $0$.

Comment: You have four + and two stars

Comment: Are the students and professors seated around a circular table, or are the seats in a line?

Comment: Line @BrianBorchers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. I get the same result by reasoning as follows:

- $7$ students in a row give $6$ "slots" where to place the professors in between.
- There are $\binom 6 4$ ways to choose the slots.
- The students and professors give $7!\cdot 4!$ arrangements for each way of choosing the "slots"
  $$\frac{\binom 6 4 \cdot 4! \cdot 7!}{11!}$$

Comment: Just to note that you can take the students to be identical, as well as the professors, in which case the denominator comes out to $(11)(10)(9)(8)/4!$ and the numerator is just 15, which of course is the same ratio (both top and bottom are reduced by a factor of $(7!)(4!)$ ).

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is incorrect. See the comments at the end.

Mine is a little different. Let's first assume that all students are identical, and all professors are identical, so we only arrange patterns. Two students must sit at the two ends (otherwise, the professors at the ends would not be between students). Now we have 5 students and 4 professors, to sit in the middle 9 seats. Since there is only one more student than professors, at most, two students can sit together (ignore the two students at the ends). In the case in which no two students sitting together, there is only one pattern: +101010101+, where + stands for the students sitting at the ends; in the case where two students are sitting together, we have 5 locations for them. So, we have 6 patterns in total. Now, with every pattern, we have 4!7! ways to arrange students and professors. So, the probability for the good is $\frac{6\cdot 4!\cdot 7!}{11!}$.

Okay, after some thought, mine is incorrect. We may have more than two students sitting together. The prior one is simpler and more elegant, and more importantly, correct!